# Rails application getting 500 error page on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm migrating a working Rails 3 application from server to another type of service. Firstly I had issues with static files (e.g. application.css, application.js) not being rendered (404 status). I resolved that issue turning the `config.assets.enabled` to true.

Now I'm having the problem of error 500 no matter where I go in the application. I assume it's an asset problem. I don't get an error in log/production. Only something as follow:

```
Started GET "/" for 187.39.38.147 at 2016-06-14 12:33:05 +0000
Processing by BooksController#index as HTML
  Rendered myapp/layouts/500.html (0.7ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 16ms (Views: 10.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

I have no idea of how to find out what's wrong to fix that. 
What can I do to find out what's wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't migrate the database over to the new host.  Without it you will get that type of "Sorry no go" response without much logging.

Comment: Actually I've made a backup of my project database. I can rails console and fetch data like this: user = User.last. Do I still need to migrate the database ?

Comment: Nope but you may still need to run any pending migrations.  Make sure the database is upto date.  Also, what are you hosting this on?  Heroku?

Comment: I don't believe it has something to do with that.. I haven't made any change...

Comment: I found out the error. There was a missing table... You ended up being right about it @bkunzi01.

Comment: Glad to help, cheers!